# Vue.js + Element - losing active menu item class when toggling menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, element-ui

I'm using Element.eleme.io UI library with Vue.js 2+ and building a vertical sidebar (docs: http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu )

The problem is, when I toggle the menu to expand/collapse, I'm losing my currently selected/active menu item (in docs it always revers to default one for example) - how to keep it between this toggle?

Currently I've even created computed value for `default-active` prop, but it still doesn't work as I would like to:

```
<el-menu
  default-active='activeSideMenuItemIndex' // computed value that gets active index from the store
  @select='updateSelectedMenuIndex' // action to update activeSideMenuItemIndex in vuex store
  :collapse='isCollapsed'
>
```

The funny/weird thing is, that after toggling the menu, the `default-active` prop is set properly, but the active menu item class disappears so user don't know which item is selected.

Comment: Maybe it sets menu display: none and you lose data, try to save active item outside of that sidebar or if you already use vuex, thats easiest way to implement.